# Solution for progress bar in web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple to do list app I'm making with html/css/js. You type in a task, add it, the task it then displayed on a page in an li element. If I select a task, it is highlighted and I'm taken to another page. This page just has a "Done" button on it. Once I press this button, I'm given a popup that asks how much I completed of the current task I'm working on on a scale from 1 to 10 which I can select with a slider. 10 represents 100% of the task being complete. Here's where I need help. I want a progress bar to represent the number I chose with the slider, only for that specific task which I've selected on the previous page. So if I have 10 tasks, I select one, when I'm selecting with the slider how much of it I got finished on a scale from 1 to 10, that specific task I chose will display a progress bar representing what I chose with the slider without the other tasks also displaying the same. I was thinking maybe when I add a task, a newly generated class can be appended to that specific li element? this is how the slider will be able to only apply a progress representing the number I chose for that specific task? Sorry if I'm not making sense. I'm tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Html5 tag Progress Tag
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp
example

```
<progress value="22" max="100">
</progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php    hi give this  a try it should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use that the way I'd like?

Comment: You really need to be more clear, that is a full working example of progress bars being populated by dynamic data. This method should be applicable to most cases.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. If I have multiple "tasks" displayed within multiple <li> elements on a page, how can I target the progress bar of a specific task and have it display progress based on the number I've selected with a slider on another page between 1-10. So, "On a scale from 1-10, how much of the task have you completed?" If I select 10, then the progress bar contained in the li element with the current task I'm working on should be 100%. The issue is that the li elements don't have any id's or classes to target it specifically so I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Sorry again,tired

Comment: Just select the class and the element you want it to update, i.e  $("#pb4").progressBar(65, ... that takes a value of 0-100 so if you only want to use a scale of 1-10 then just multiply your scale by 10.

Comment: right but the <li> elements don't have classes or id's. When I add a task, it's text in an li element appended to a UL. How can I make sure each li has a unique class or id generated and then make it so the page with the slider will apply the number I select 1-10 to the progress bar only on that specific task. So the progress bar for that specific task will not be applied to other tasks.

Comment: sorry mate i crashed out this morning, in your code when creating the list. just assign each element with an id. if its created dynamically then you will have to check the count, loop through and add each id, incrementing by one.  does that make sense ?